# Tricky C# syntax for out function parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, queue

I'm familiar with using out to pass in a simple data type for manipulation, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass in this `Queue<>` without causing a compile error.  Any ideas?

Code:

```
Queue<SqlCommand> insertScriptQueue = new Queue<SqlCommand>();

private void UpdateDefaultIndicator(int newDefaultViewID,
                                    out (Queue<SqlCommand>) insertScriptQueue)

UpdateDefaultIndicator(newViewID, out (Queue<SqlCommand>)insertScriptQueue);
```

Comment: What compiler error are you getting? And try omitting the ( ) around Queue on the second line of code. 
Also style the code as code by using the 101010 button above the edit field. It makes it a lot better readable :)

Comment: What is the type of `insertScriptQueue` in your invocation of `UpdateDefaultIndicator`?  It looks like you are casting the parameter, which is illegal in conjunction with using `out`.

Comment: Given the number of apparent problems with this code, it would be nice if you could post the code that worked for you.

Comment: Robert, replace `out` with `ref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Queue is going to be passed by reference anyway, its not a value type.  Just don't use 'out'.  UPDATE: Pardon me, I was thinking of 'ref' - but the fact that you're passing a Queue data type in, and not just an unallocated reference, makes me think that you want to be using 'ref' anyway.  Except of course that you don't need to use 'ref' because the Queue isn't a value type; its already going to be passed in 'by reference', by default.

Comment: It's not going to be passed "by reference" - the reference will be passed by value. It's a subtle difference, but an important one. "ref" and "out" can still be important with reference types. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Thanks!  Excellent detail.  So while Queue is a reference type, the necessity for a 'ref' parameter depends on whether or not he sets that parameter to a different Queue object in his function, with the expectation of the caller seeing the new object.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing in a reference type.  No need to use out.

Comment: What does `out` have to do with passing a reference type? The `out` modifier simply allows you to use an uninitialised variable (which can be a value-type or ref-type) and ensures that it is initialised in the method itself.

Comment: Okay; no need to use out OR ref in this particular context.  He's initialized his variable already before passing it in.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be initializing an out variable.  If you need to modify an in-scope variable, use ref instead.

As Ed points out in his comment, "modify" may not give you the full idea of what's happening here - an out parameter of a reference type will by definition be an initialized object at the end of the function call.  As most other answers have pointed out, if you want to pass in an initialized object, ref is the stronger choice.

Comment: You really mean "if you need to modify a variable that is a value type or assign a new object to the parameter for a reference type"

Comment: I checked the docs, it appears it actually is ok to initialize an out variable; presumably the reference to the old value is discarded when the function returns a new one.

Answer (score 3):

```
Queue<SqlCommand> insertScriptQueue;

private void UpdateDefaultIndicator(int newDefaultViewID,
                                out Queue<SqlCommand> insertScriptQueue){/*body*/}

UpdateDefaultIndicator(newViewID,out insertScriptQueue);
```

That works fine for me... What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want a "out" ...here...why dont you return the type instead ? Let method return Queue<> insteasd of void..will that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are assigning insertScriptQueue some kind of value inside of the UpdateDefaultIndicator method

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question, by the way, is that you're casting to Queue, and the cast is returning an interim reference.  That reference is not assignable, and so is not a legal out parameter.  Erich's code implements the fix for this problem.